# Cocoa binding between 2 property in different classes

Tags: cocoa, binding, cocoa-bindings

I am about 2 weeks in learning cocoa, currently I am trying to understand bindings, can I bind 2 non UI properties together?

I tried bind them programmatically, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
[ClassA bind: @"property1"
       toObject: ClassB // <--------Error here 
    withKeyPath:@"propert2"
        options:bindingOptions];
```

I think I might be getting it wrong all together, any help or direction will be appreciated.

Thank in advance,

Regards,
Terence

Comment: To be honest, if you're only two weeks into learning Cocoa then I'd forget bindings for a bit and learn to do everything the "hard way" first.

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- It is perfectly valid to bind an arbitrary property to another property. This is often useful in automatically updating the UI, which is why many of Apple's examples showcase user interface element properties. But bindings are not restricted to UI objects in any way. See below for a concrete example:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  StackOverflow
//
//  Created by Stephen Poletto on 10/15/11.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ClassA : NSObject {
    NSString *propertyA;
}

@property (copy) NSString *propertyA;

@end

@interface ClassB : NSObject {
    NSString *propertyB;
}

@property (copy) NSString *propertyB;

@end

@implementation ClassA
@synthesize propertyA;
@end

@implementation ClassB
@synthesize propertyB;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    ClassA *a = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    ClassB *b = [[ClassB alloc] init];

    [a bind:@"propertyA" toObject:b withKeyPath:@"propertyB" options:nil];

    // Now that the binding has been established, if propertyB is set on 'b',
    // propertyA will automatically be updated to have the same value.
    [b setPropertyB:@"My Message"];
    NSLog(@"A's propertyA: %@", [a propertyA]); // Prints 'MyMessage'. Success!
}

@end
```

Please note that bind: is called on an instance of a class, not on the class itself. If you're new to Cocoa, you should know that bindings are one of the more difficult concepts, and you should make sure you understand KVC and KVO before using them.